# AngularJS - Get parameter from URL when parameter is not the last item in the address

Tags: angularjs, location

I am trying to work out in AngularJS how to obtain parameters from a URL when the parameter is not the last thing in the address.

For example, how do I obtain the `uid` from the following URL?

http://myhost/?uid=12345#/auth

`$location.search()` returns me an emptry array

`$location.absUrl()` returns me `http://myhost/?uid=12345#/auth`

`$location.url()` returns me `/auth`

I'm sure this has probably already been answered, but I can't seem to find a decent example.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<base>` tag to get `.search()` working, and then using `$location.search().uid`?

Comment: I have tried `$location.search().uid` which still returns me `undefinded` but I'm not sure what you mean about adding a `<base>` tag.  Could you explain further please.  Thanks

Comment: From 1.3 onwards, you need to add in a `<base>` tag so that it knows the path that links are relative to. You can achieve this with `<base href="/" />`. Otherwise you can always use a regex based off  of `.absUrl()` :)